# What is the space on the right of images in chrome?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Consider the following [example](https://jsfiddle.net/r6oycnvu/):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        td {
            padding: 0;
            background: red;
        }
        img {
            display: block;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body
    ><table
    ><tr
      ><td
        ><img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sinatra/sinatra/v1.4.7/lib/sinatra/images/500.png"
      ></td
    ></tr
    ></table
></body>
</html>
```

There's a red line in `chrome` on the right of the image. No such line in `firefox`. It doesn't seem like a space, because the html markup has no spaces between tags. It doesn't seem like a margin, because Developer tools doesn't report any margin.

What is this? How much space could it take?

I'm running `chromium-47.0.2526.111` (64-bit), if anything.

**UPD** I made an example without spaces specifically to show that the red line is not caused by spaces.

Next, it was found the line appears when Zoom is, for instance, 110%. So, everything is supposedly clear now.

Comment: Cannot reproduce on `Chrome 48.0.2564.116 m`

Comment: I am not seeing any space or red line to the right of the image. I am on Version 48.0.2564.109 m. I don't know what you have for extensions but did you consider disabling them all and seeing if it still exists?

Comment: I don't see any red line

Comment: This red is from the background you have set. Not sure why this is there though. Can you just get rid of that part of the CSS?

Comment: No red line on Version 48.0.2564.116 m

Comment: remove margin from body..

Comment: Guys, try zooming, you will see it!

Comment: It's because of how you calculate percentages and whole numbers.

Comment: If I added `width:100%` to the image, the problem is fixed - see fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/f8qgjqjp/1/

Comment: @Aziz Nope that is not a fix: http://i.imgur.com/mFOBpHl.png http://i.imgur.com/I8Qdnv9.png and http://i.imgur.com/3pz09D1.png

Comment: width:100% also isn't working for me. Haven't had any luck with the answers on this page unfortunately. Retina macbook with Chrome 62.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is because of the way `<td>` elements are displayed. As you can see, they are displayed as:

```
display: table-cell;
```

This is because of how table-cell is ment to calculate pixels. Since 1 pixel is not equal to 1 pixel in CSS if you have DPI scaling enabled (or you zoom), it will start to behave weird.

You can either find another approach of your `<td>` inside `<tr>` or simply change the display to `display: inline;`

It's all because of how pixels sizes are calculated. I know it sounds weird, but 1px is not 1 physical pixel. **Essentially what happens is your td's background changes according to the size of your image. When your image hits an odd number (because of zooming or DPI scaling), it will either round down or up. This is when the calculation happens and is wrong.**

Sources: https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#absolute-lengths
http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/04/a_pixel_is_not.html

Answer (score 0):

This may help you:

```
td {
  padding: 0;
  background: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Causes when not zoomed

Since you have padding set to zero on your td element, that's fine, and the only thing that can make the same effect is to have the margin on the image (the margin on the child element sort of behaves like a padding on the parent element in this case). The margin could be set either by you, or by your browser's stylesheet (I don't see it on mine).

Set `img {margin: 0}` and it should be gone because you've covered both cases that could cause it.

---

### Zooming problem

If you see it only when zooming, it's because of browser's sub-pixel rendering (when the pixel values become floats and the browser starts rounding or flooring them). And due to the extremely non-power-of-two dimensions of the image (313x161) it's highly likely to get that extra pixel line on various zoom levels when, say at 110% zoom, the calculated width of the td is **313.636 pixels**, and the image **312.997 pixels**, which become 313 and 312 when floored. That leaves us with the td element being one pixel wider than its child image, which is where the line (the red td background not being "covered" by the image) comes from.

`img {width: 100%}` fixes this (as Aziz already said in the comments)

Comment: Everything's clear after we get to the point where calculated widths differ. But what brings us to that point?

Answer (score 0):

There is no red line for me on initial load, however I can see red lines if I zoom in, which begs the question, **is your browser set to zoomed in?**

Look for the magnifying glass in the url bar of google chrome and make sure you're set to 100%

[image]

Comment: It doesn't really explain where the line comes from, and the zoom issue was mentioned in the comments long ago.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is that for several years Chrome has handled images in tables defectively and no one can comprehend that this the actual problem. You have to take the images out of the table and put them in divs...

Comment: This would be more helpful if you can explain why tables (and not divs) display a red bar.